# Apache CXF How to responde with custom validation error

Tags: java, spring, web-services, cxf

I have simple cxf 3.1.1 soap web service.

```
@WebService
public interface MyService {
    @WebMethod
    public MyResponse addSomeModel(MyRequest req) throws SoapValidationException;
}
```

And the Implementation:

```
@Component
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com...MyService", serviceName="Myservice")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
@Override
    public MyResponse addSomeModel(MyRequest req) throws SoapValidationException {
        Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(req, "myReq");
        addCampaignValidator.validate(req, errors);
        if(errors.hasErrors()){
            throw new SoapValidationException("Validation error.", errors);
        }
        //... save it the DB    
        return ...;
    }
}
```

The SoapValidationException is:

```
@WebFault
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER )
public class SoapValidationException extends Exception implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Errors errors;

    public SoapValidationException(String message, Errors errors, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    public SoapValidationException(String message, Errors errors) {
        super(message);
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    public List<FieldError> getErrors() { // Here I have to use some complex type
        return errors.getFieldErrors();
    }

    public String getTargetObject(){
        return errors.getObjectName();
    }

    public int getErrorCount(){
        return errors.getErrorCount();
    }
}
```

When I use a simple type like int or String for a public getter it works ok the object is serialized and returned as xml. 
But I want to use some complex type, like in the example I use the `FieldError` from Spring validation.

What I have to do, so I can use a complex type as a field of `SoapValidationException`?

It's not required to use `FieldError`, I can also wite my own wrapper and map the proeprties.

Answer (score 0):

Since CXF uses JAXB, the custom type has to be a valid jaxb element.

I ended up with:

```
@WebFault
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER )
public class SoapValidationException extends Exception implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Errors errors;

    public SoapValidationException(String message, Errors errors, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    public SoapValidationException(String message, Errors errors) {
        super(message);
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    public String getErrors() {
        return errors.toString();
    }

    public List<ValidationExceptionDetails> getDetails(){
        List<ValidationExceptionDetails> details = new ArrayList<ValidationExceptionDetails>();
        for(FieldError fe : errors.getFieldErrors()) {
            details.add(new ValidationExceptionDetails(fe.getCode(), fe.getDefaultMessage(), fe.getRejectedValue().toString()));
        }
        return details;
    }
}
```

Where the ValidationExceptionDetails is:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ValidationExceptionDetails {
    private String code;
    private String message;
    private String rejectedValue;

    public ValidationExceptionDetails(String code, String message, String rejectedValue) {
        this.code = code;
        this.message = message;
        this.rejectedValue = rejectedValue;
    }

    public ValidationExceptionDetails() {
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public String getRejectedValue() {
        return rejectedValue;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public void setRejectedValue(String rejectedValue) {
        this.rejectedValue = rejectedValue;
    }


}
```